# I need to reverse this PPC Line: clrldi r11, r31, 32

Tags: powerpc, xbox

I need to reverse this PPC Line: clrldi    r11, r31, 32      I know clrldi it means Clear Left Word Double Immediate. But I dont know how to reverse it so can someone give me advise on reversing it. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a little time to go through the [about] and [help] pages so you understand how this site works before posting your next question. This is not a "Please be my personal assistant" site. If you have questions, post them *here*, in public, where people can answer them and others can benefit from the question and answer. If you want a personal helper, hire someone to tutor or consult with you. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to generating a mask of zeroes from bit 0-31 and ones from bit 32-63, so the mask is 0x00000000FFFFFFFF. The mask is ANDed with r31 and the result is placed in r11. The mask clears the left side of the register. Check out rldicl and how the extended mnemonic clrldi is interpreted in the [PowerPC User ISA Book 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-archguide-v2.html). It will help explain it as well.

If I were to code this in C, it would look like:

```
r11 = r31 & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFLL;
```